# Adding listbox items doesn't work in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, listbox

In xamarin forms development , adding items to listbox doesn't work well.

MainPage.xaml

```
  <ListBox  x:Name="vrlist_panel">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            ....
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding leftImg}" Height="100" Margin="14,2,13,20"></Image>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding rightImg}" Height="100" Margin="14,2,13,20"></Image>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

  </ListBox>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public class VRDataModel
{
    public string leftImg { get; set; }

    public string rightImg { get; set; }
}


public partitial class MainPage : Page , 
                                    Autodesk.Revit.UI.IDockablePaneProvider
{
         ....
     private static ObservableCollection<VRDataModel> vrImgs = new 
                                       ObservableCollection<VRDataModel>();
         ....
}


    ...
vrlist_panel.ItemsSource = vrImgs;
    ...
```

Here is entire code.
But even though vrImgs is valid value, the value of `vrlist_panel.ItemsSource` is `null` on runtime and it causes exception.
I have been trying to fix this issue for several days but couldn't find the reason.
How should I do?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be XF - it doesn't support a ListBox.

Comment: Really?  
Then why doesn't the error occur on compile?  
If it doesn't support a listbox , compile has to be failed.
Could you explain about this?

Comment: I suspect that whatever you're building isn't really an XF app - it appears to be WPF or UWP

Comment: In my opinion, XF is a platform and WPF is a GUI framework.
So I thought we used WPF to design in XF.
Actually I don't have much experiences in xamarin , so could you please explain about WPF and XF?   
Such as difference.

Comment: WPF won't run on iOS or Android, XF will.  XF is already well documented - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thanks.  I see.
Then I think I am using WPF.    Could you please help me about above issue?

Comment: Edit your question and tag it appropriately to get an answer.

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting and where?

Comment: Where are you setting `vrlist_panel.ItemsSource`?  You snipped out the context, so we have no idea when this is supposedly happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is incomplete but if you are getting a `NullReferenceException` when trying to set the `ItemsSource` property, you are probably not calling the `InitializeComponent()` method prior to setting the property:

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
        vrlist_panel.ItemsSource = vrImgs;
    }
}
```